# Nilpotent elements of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_3 [x] / I$, where $I= <x^2-1>$ . I need to find **how many** are the **nilpotent** elements of $R$, i.e. the elements $a \in R$ for which there exists a natural $n$ such that $a^n=0_R$ .

Let $f(x)+I \in R$ be a nilpotent element. Then, for some $n$,  $(f(x)+I)^n = 0+I = I $. Can someone tell me what's the direct conclusion of the last equality? 
Is it right to imply that $(f(x))^n \in <x^2 -1>$ ?
I need a clue to proceed to the solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By the *Chinese remainder theorem*,
$$R\simeq \mathbf F_3[x]/(x-1)\times\mathbf F_3[x]/(x+1)\simeq \mathbf F_3\times\mathbf F_3,$$
which is reduced ring: there are no non-zero nilpotent elements.